# Tollbar with a notification count

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Hello I'm using a Tollbar and inside I added some drawable items in the menu options. What I want is to put a number inside those drawable. Like the image below

[View post on imgur.com](//imgur.com/tw7hdSD)

I know there are other post related to this but not with a Toolbar and I need to is a Toolbar.

Thank you

Comment: Make A xml For Background  for textview in toolbar so that appears like counter  i can demostrate it you want to see

Comment: Sure can you show me?  How do i do that? becasue I know I can add items to the toolbar, I dont know how to add a TextView

Comment: @GerardoMendezDot Check out details in my answer. Just add menu with custom layout.

Comment: @GerardoMendezDot  hi, does any of the answers worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way is to use TextView with star background:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notification"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_height"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_star"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    tools:text="5" />
```

You can use obvious TextView's setText() method to set or hide notification text.

To add this layout to your Toolbar use Android menu's `app:actionLayout` parameter:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notifications"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/view_notification"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

And in your Activity inflate menu like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notification_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ok but I'm using this to add the toolbar. 
Toolbar miActionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.miActionBar);
setSupportActionBar(miActionBar);
WIll it work?

Comment: Yes. It's correct way to use menu items if you want to show actions in Toolbar. Check [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


         <TextView


            android:background="@drawable/bg_star"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Toolbar Title"
            android:id="@+id/notification"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


       Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
       TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```